# Need to get image tag in wechat mini program

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I'm trying to get the image src from wxml. All of the image src should be obtained and replaced.

What should replace **document.getElementsByTagName** in Wechat Mini?

Answer (score 1):

js:
var that = this;

```
    var query = wx.createSelectorQuery();
    
    query.select('.classname').boundingClientRect(function (params) {
        cosnole.log(params)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working. can we add node to parent node from js? Is there any replacement for document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(node); tag in wechat mini program?

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. Regarding your second question, I did some research and the answer to this question is "no". Usually we use the data in data to control the node. For example, "wx-if" (just like "v-if in Vue"). If you want to add child nodes to a parent node, you should generally control the addition or deletion of nodes based on the addition or deletion of data.
For example:

Comment: There is an array [1,2,3], rendering three "li" by "wx-for". If you want to change (add or remove) one of them, please change the array directly, instead of using the traditional "js's dom"

Comment: WeChat doesn't encourage you to manipulate dom directly, you should drive the view through data like "vue".
Change the view by modifying the data with "this.setdata"

Answer (score 0):

As for your original question, perhaps you could use a "custom property" (data-xxx) to get your src

```
<image src="{{src}}" data-src="{{src}}" bindtap="ontap" />
js:
Page({
    data: {
        src:'1.jpg'
    },
 
    ontap:function(e) {
        const {src} = e.currentTarget.dataset;
        console.log(src);
    }
})
```